# unable to connect to firebase and app crashs

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to firebase in Android Studio 3.2.1. After applying the `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'`, the firebase dependencies are setup correctly and the moment I remove 15.0.0, the firebase dependencies get disconnected. Also when connected to phone (Android version 7.1.1, System version26.31.1) the app crashed.

How do I proceed?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Comment: you are using different compilation version of firebase libraries use same i.e '16.0.1' for all and check weather it works.

Comment: use the same Dependency for all firebase. either use '16.0.1'  for all  or use       
 16.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

You can try entering the following dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
```

This worked for me, hope this works for you too...

If you are right now using the latest version of android studio 2021.2.1, you can automatically add the dependencies by clicking on the **tools** in toolbar and then **firebase**, the assistant will open up, now look for **realtime database**, connect to firebase, add the **realtime database SDK to your app** and select accept changes. This will add all the important dependencies...